# Apply style where class does not have id present

Tags: css, mmenu

How do i apply a style to all but the first element:

```
<div class = "mm-current" id="mm-1"></div>
<div class = "mm-current" id="mm-2"></div>
<div class = "mm-current" id="mm-3"></div>
...// Dynamic amount of entries
```

I have tried this:

```
.mm-current:not( #mm-1 )
{
    background-image: url( "Images/trans-white-background-strong.png" ) !important;
}
```

But this unfortunately is not working (the style is being applied regardless of the element having `id="mm-1"` on it)

Comment: "apply a style to only the first element" You mean apply a style to only the second and third ones? What you have should work as described. You'll have to tell us what "not working" means.

Comment: Thanks man, i've amended the question.

Comment: Your selector should work fine as far as I know (that is, it would set the background image to all `.mm-current` except the one whose id is `mm-1`). Maybe there is some problem elsewhere. Can you create a verifiable example?

Comment: Gosh, harry you're right... Oh how annoying. Thanks man... Must be something else going on brahhh

Answer (score 0):

When using classes, applying a style just to the first element, do this:

```
.mm-current:first-child
{
    background-image: url( "Images/trans-white-background-strong.png" )!important;
}
```

Hopefully your problem is solved, greetings.

---

Edit #1: You could just do the same, when you want just a specific style for one element. No styles is a style aswell, if you know what I mean:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zvg5f6b/1/

Fiddle with image: http://jsfiddle.net/3zvg5f6b/2/

Comment: I have made a change that may alter the question. I need to style all... BUT the first one :)

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Added a new Fiddle, you could just do the same thing, as I mentioned before. Are you sure, that you got the right path? Are your Stylesheets in a Subfolder like css? Just like your Images-Folder?

Then your URL-Path should be background-image: url( "../Images/trans-white-background-strong.png");